# Como configurar um projeto java comum, hospedar e rodar num servidor

Tags: java, jsf, loop, servidor, tomcat

Opa, boa noite galera, to com algumas dúvidas sobre sistemas java rodando sem servidor.

Eu e uns amigos estamos desenvolvendo um projeto de integração em java (nós recebemos uma informação de um servidor/serviço, tratamos no nosso sistema e depois repassamos para outro serviço (como email ou trello)), nosso programa roda perfeitamente nas nossas máquinas porém não sabemos como fazer para configurar esse projeto para rodar num servidor.

O programa teria que estar escutando a todo momento a chegada de uma informação de um dos serviços, como isso seria feito? colocar um while infinito e tratar quando chegar algo ou existe uma função para tal? e caso chegue outra informação no meio tempo em que o sistema esteja processando algo, como evitar q seja perdido, já que o programa não estaria escutando e sim cuidando do processamento dos dados que vieram antes?

Além disso, o projeto foi feito em java normal (sem jsf, war ou tomcat instalado), como eu converteria para um tipo de projeto que seria aceito por um serviço de hospedagem (tem algum em específico ou recomendado?)

Alguma dica ou recomendação de serviço de hospedagem? eu consegui 2 meses grátis no serviço da Uol Host Cloud Openstack, consigo utilizar ele para o que estou querendo ou é necessário uma hospedagem de site em java?

Muito obrigado e desculpe pelas inúmeras perguntas :/

Comment: João Pedro Silva Dezembro, que tal realizar o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) de boas-vindas do SOpt? Dessa forma você poderá usufruir ao máximo do fórum e dos usuários.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, boa noite. Você não especificou que tipo que informação espera como entrada no java, mas, independentemente, você precisa utilizar um conceito chamado **Threads**! 
Cada thread é uma execução em paralelo no java, ou seja, você pode ter vários processos ao mesmo tempo. 
Resumindo, você poderia fazer com um while true e quando receber uma requisição (chegada da informação esperada), o sistema abre uma thread para aquela requisição e assim o sistema continuará a esperar outra requisição enquanto processa a anterior.
Espero que tenha ajudado :)

Comment: Vamos receber jsons, já fizemos o código do tratamento do modelo que iremos receber porém no momento estamos apenas carregando de um arquivo local. Outra dúvida que tenho é exatamente como seria feito essa "escuta" para aguardar uma requisição de um serviço externo. Eles enviariam por um endereço nosso porém como faço p ouvir e salvar esses dados que eles vão nos enviar?

Mto obg!

(Aliás, já havia escutado sobre Threads mas nunca pesquisei a fundo, vou dar uma olhada melhor agora)

Comment: Bom neste caso, dê uma pesquisada sobre Servlet em java. Os Servlets tem a função de realizar a comunicação cliente-servidor e pode ser a solução para seu problema. Também recomendo você da uma lida sobre REST e RESTFul para futuros projetos! Não vai se arrepender !